# How to make a function to calculate prevalence of "1" in a column contain '0' and '1' only and make graphs?

Tags: r, ggplot2, aggregate

```
Group1 <- c('A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B')
Group2 <- c('1','1','2','1','2','1','1','2','1','2','2','2','2','1','1','2')
Value <- c('1','0','0','1','1','0','0','0','0','1','1','1','1','0','1','0')
df <- data.frame(Group1,Group2,Value)
```

I want to make a graph using ggplot2 like this (link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipSe6.jpg), showing the percentage of value '1' by group2, comparing group A and B.

I want to make similar graphs for different columns, so I think defining a function to calculate the percentage and then use 'aggregate' would be a solution. But I can't make it.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest next approach using `dplyr` and `ggplot2`. You have to process your data by grouping by `Group1` and `Group2` to obtain the total values and the compute the percentages based on `Group2`. Next code include those steps using `summarise()` and `mutate()` functions:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#Data
Group1 <- c('A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B') 
Group2 <- c('1','1','2','1','2','1','1','2','1','2','2','2','2','1','1','2') 
Value <- c('1','0','0','1','1','0','0','0','0','1','1','1','1','0','1','0') 
df <- data.frame(Group1,Group2,Value,stringsAsFactors = F)
df$Value <- as.numeric(df$Value)
#Compute
df %>% group_by(Group1,Group2) %>%
  #Compute totals
  summarise(Val=sum(Value)) %>%
  #Compute percentages
  group_by(Group2) %>% mutate(Percentage=Val/sum(Val)) %>%
  #Plot
  ggplot(aes(x=Group2))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity',aes(y=Percentage,fill=Group1),position = position_dodge(0.9))+
  theme_bw()
```

The output is close to what you want:

[image]

Comment: It helps me a lot. Thank you!

Comment: @GraceT Great! If you believe this answer was helpful for you, you could accept it by clicking the tick on the left side of this answer :)